# problems getting mod_rewrite working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've not done much with mod_rewrite, but I can't seem to get anywhere with this. I'm wondering if perhaps it is not enabled on my server(even though my host says it is).

I have the following url: http://dev.website.com/folder1/translate/horse and I want that to redirect to: http://dev.website.com/folder1/translate.php?word=horse

My .htaccess starts with RewriteEngine on and I've tried various  attempts to get it working, but no matter what, it just shows my home page (the default 404 redirect).

Things I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^translate/.*$ translate.php?word=$1
RewriteRule ^translate translate.php
```

and some other things I don't remember, but I can't get anything to work.

The .htaccess file I am using is located in folder1. I have also tried putting random characters in the file to make it throw an error, and it does.

Anything I'm missing? How would I properly create this redirect?

As per request, this is my file structure.

I have the domain www.website.com, and a subdomain dev.website.com. The subdomain is set so that it redirects to www.website.com/dev. So, in this case, dev.website.com/folder1/translate.php = www.website.com/dev/folder1/translate.php. I am not sure how that masking is done, as it is accomplished via my web host's cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't capturing `$1` in brackets so this should work:

**In DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^folder1/translate/(.*)$ /folder1/translate.php?word=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**In DOCUMENT_ROOT/folder1/.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder1/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^translate/(.*)$ translate.php?word=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I had tried something similar to that before. Using that right now still shows the homepage (minus the css because of the folder structure). My .htaccess is this:

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^translate/(.*)$ translate.php?word=$1 [L,QSA]
it seems like there is another setting somewhere messing this up.

Comment: For css, js, try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: But it is better to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want it to display the home page. The home page is dev.website.com/index.php. That is being shown instead of the dev.website.com/folder1/translate.php, the css was simply a side note, and wont matter.

Comment: Nope, same problem. Displays the homepage (which is my default 404 setting).

Comment: Is this .htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT or in folder1?

Comment: It was in folder1, but neither of those worked. I'm wondering if the problem has to do with my setup. dev.website.com is really redirected to the folder dev, so dev.website.com/index.php = website.com/dev/index.php

Comment: Can you tell me how this is done: `dev.website.com is really redirected to the folder dev`?

Comment: My web host has an option for sub-domains, when I created the dev subdomain it asked how I wanted it to work, a separate hosting account, or a folder/directory within the existing host, I chose the latter. I'm not sure how exactly that is done, as it is set up through my webhost's control panel

Comment: So `website.com/dev` is DOCUMENT_ROOT for `dev.website.com`?

Comment: as far as I can tell, yes.

Comment: Then what is folder1? I am unable to understand your file/directory structure, your current & desired URL scheme and current rules in place. If you can provide all these details in your question I will come back to this question to suggest you an updated answer to solve your problem.